# Reverse double in c# without using string or array

Tags: c#

I know such questions have been asked before, but all of them use strings.

Most common answers to such questions are :

1. convert to string and take `number.Length - 1`. However I don't want to use strings.
2. Divide by 10, but this only works for whole numbers. If I have 1.12 and I divide it by 10 I dont get 2.
3. Turn the number into array and then reverse it. Which is the same as using a string but more work and its not what I am looking for.

So my question is if I have input like 1.12 I want 21.1 but without using any strings. I want to take the 2 and save it as a number and then take the rest and add the dot.

I want a mathematical solution to the problem.

I will provide you with some test cases so you better understand my problem.

```
23.45 => 54.32
0.50 => 05.0 => 5
4.3445242 => 2425443.4
232 => 232
123 => 321
```

And I dont want strings or arrays because when you say "I dont want strings" there is always someone who says " turn the number into array and then reverse it". Nah... I want to use only calculations, if-else and cycles (for,while,do while)

Comment: Maybe a math forum would be a better place for this. It's more of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: *"I want a mathematical solution"* then ask your question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use strings? I don't understand why you have the most common answer but don't want to use it. It's probably a common answer for a reason: It works.

Comment: Start by thinking about this: You do not really show doubles but decimals in your post. Then continue to think about digts!  - Eventually you will  come up with a solution and/or accept that using strings is a vastly superior approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively ugly way would be essentially promote that double into long and remember the decimal point. Then reverse the long, then divide it by total number of digits minus originl decimal point. Also, if you want to handle negative numbers, you would have to store the sign and Math.Abs the src double you start mucking around with it.

```
private double Reverse(double src)
{
    double dst = 0;
    int decPoint = 0;          

    while (src - (long)src > 0)
    {
        src = src * 10;
        decPoint++;
    }

    int totalDigits = 0;

    while (src > 0)
    {
        int d = (int)src % 10;
        dst = dst * 10 + d;
        src = (long)(src / 10);
        totalDigits++;
    }        

    if (decPoint > 0)
    {
        int reversedDecPoint = totalDigits - decPoint;
        for (int i = 0; i < reversedDecPoint; i++) dst = dst / 10;
    }

    return dst;
}
```

Comment: This suffers from [floating-point accuracy problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems). Consider `double d = 1.12 * 10;` where you get `d = 11.200000000000001`.

Comment: and exactly for the reason cited by @AhmedAbdelhameed, OP problem has no solution when dealing with double, since 1.12 is maybe internally stored as something like 1.120000000000001 or 1.19999999999999999

Comment: Of course. Then again, I figured with artificial restrictions a'la no arrays, that thing will only ever need to run past test data anyway :)